# How can i only read Strings or Integers when i read .txt file with Scanner Class in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, java.util.scanner, java-io

Hey guys this is my first question so if i have any mistakes or faults , i am sorry about that.

So i am working on one thing which i'm currently keep failing of and that is ,as it says in the title, reading only strings and integers from .txt file. Here is my code:

```
 File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Enes\\Desktop\\test.txt");
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(file);
    String[] s = new String[10];
    int i = 0;
    int[] fruits = new int[10];

    while (scn.hasNextInt()) {

        fruits[i++] = scn.nextInt();

    }while (scn.hasNext()) {

        s[i++] = scn.next();

    }

    for (int elm : fruits) {
        System.out.print(elm + "\t");
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    for (String ele : s) {
        System.out.print(ele + "\t");
    }
```

And here is what writes on .txt file

```
Apple 5
Pear 3
```

Output is like:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
Apple   5   Pear    3   null    null    null    null    null    null
```

So i want to get Apple and Pear, the strings in different array and 5 and 3 which is integers in different array. How can i do this? Any help would be so appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: If you ever get tired of typing all those doubled backslashes you can just use forward slashes `"C:/Users/Enes/Whatever/Wherever"`

Comment: Oh yes i didn't know that. Thanks for the tip David! I will definetly use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd rename your variables to something useful:

```
String[] names = new String[10];
int[] counts = new int[10];
```

Right now, you're trying to grab all 10 numbers and then all 10 names. But that isn't how your data is laid out.

I would use the scanner to grab the line, and split it from there:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(file));
int index = 0;
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
    names[index] = tokens[0];
    counts[index] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
    index++;
}
```

For output, we iterate both loops at the same time:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(names[i] + "\t" + counts[i]);
}
```

Comment: This is correct and there's nothing wrong with it, but, you could use a second `Scanner` to parse the `line` instead of using `String` parsing tools - just saying ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer You could, I suppose. It doesn't seem the right tool for the job but I suppose if you really hate arrays you could do that. String.split is microoptimized for single character splits though...

Comment: No, what I mean is `Scanner` can parse a `String` - people seem to forget this ;) - I mean I dislike arrays and would use a `List` and a POJO, but I respect the fact that the OP might not be ready for that :D

Comment: Ah, yeah I think that's a perfectly valid point. And you're right, it isn't nearly as common, but is certainly useful. I use it for parsing command lines and network protocol lines quite often. I think if the format wasn't single character delimited (for example, the spec allowed you to separate by ether tab or space) then a scanner would be better than `split`.

Comment: Thank you my kind sir! You are a life saver. Thank you for your response and improving my code. But there is little flaw on there it seems. It should be String[] tokens = line.split(" ");. Thank you once again. It worked !

Comment: @EnesÇalışkan You're absolutely right, that's a `String[]` - my b.

Comment: @EnesÇalışkan If you found the answer useful, please accept it as the correct answer (nice tick next to the question)

Comment: @EnesÇalışkan I would encourage you to post your completed work to codereview.stackexchange.com - you'll find you can get great feedback there. Note they only accept fully working code, they do not accept partially completed or buggy code. Stack Overflow is for fixing bugs, Code Review is for improving working code.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Ideally, you don't use an array at all - you dump them into an `ArrayList<FruitInventory>` - but as it stands there is no index out of bounds exception - the last 5 entries woudl be empty. As it stands, if there's 15 entries, you only get the first 10 printed though.

Answer (score 0):

This is an adaption of corsiKa's answer (which is-in-of-itself, correct +1), but which demonstrates using a second `Scanner` to parse the `line` ...

```
int index = 0;
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    names[index] = lineScanner.next();
    counts[index] = lineScanner.nextInt();
    index++;
}
```

because people seem to forget that `Scanner` can parse `String` values